# How can I use a SharedWorker from another worker?

Tags: service-worker, web-worker, shared-worker

The docs for [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) state that you can use it from other workers:

[image]

Except when I try to use it from either a Worker or SharedWorker context I get a ReferenceError:

[image]

*Chrome Version 114.0.5735.106*

Is there a different API I should be using to get to the SharedWorker constructor?